# PhantomJSDriver FindElements()

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJSDriver and trying to add some elements to an array
with an intention to do something along the lines of

```
var myElements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("bla")); 
myElements. ? ... (ElementAt() missing..)
```

How come ElementAt()does not show in the this case (The only reasonable available option that shows is IndexOf) ?

Comment: What do you expect it to show and what does it show? It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: Hi, I'm aggregating all page elements with the id "bla" into the myElements array. Then I want to 'handle' one of them (Click it, look into it etc). In the past I've been using ElementsAt to point to the element I'm after. In this case, ElementAt is not available hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure ElementAt() is not deprecated?

FindElements(By) returns a ReadOnlyCollection of IWebElement

Source: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_FindElements.htm

ReadOnlyCollection does not have ElementAt() as a method.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474

If you just want to find and do something to one of the elements in that collection, you can always use a foreach loop. Pseudo-ish code below:

```
        foreach (IWebElement element in myElements)
        {
            //If element matches the one I want
            //then do something i.e. Click it              
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that SpartaSixZero. I Was hoping there was a 'more direct' way to address an element. Do you reakon iterating thru the array is the only way ?

Comment: As I understand it, your element does not have a unique id. If it did, you can simply use driver.FindElement(By.id("myUniqueId")) to get the single, unique element. The fact that many elements share the id means that you can't tell for sure until you compare each one using a loop.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. Though an edge case, sometimes you need to deal with an element based on it's relative location as there is no other option (All ids are same etc). Xpath is a quick solution but placing particular elements (All checkboxes on the page for example) in an array and choosing the 3rd or 4th would give an elegant approach.